# Unable to locate web element on microsoft login screen using Xamarin.UITest

Tags: adal, xamarin.uitest

## Issue -1

Test scripts are unable to find the elements on microsoft login screen with the ADAL v5.2.0 on iOS devices on the other hand test scripts are able to find elements on microsoft login screen with the ADAL v5.2.0 on Android devices.

## Issue -2

I have been facing issues with the ADAL v5.2.0 on iOS devices. We are unable to inspect web elements on microsoft login screen and getting an error( refer to attached screenshot) when trying to inspect using Repl() command. However when we are trying the same thing on ADAL v3.19.8 on iOS devices it is working fine.[ErrorScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZNLQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

For issue 2 you can do the following steps:

1. Select the Settings application/icon on the iPhone home screen.
2. Select Safari on the following screen.
3. Select Advanced, located near the bottom of the following screen.
4. Move the JavaScript toggle to the right so that it highlights green.

Comment: I have tried the above mentioned steps for Issue 2 but still i am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

For Issue 2 try the following steps:

1. Tap the "Settings" icon on the home screen
2. Scroll the Settings sidebar until you can see the Safari icon
3. Tap the "Safari" menu option
4. Scroll the "Safari" settings section down to the "Advanced" option.
5. Find the "JavaScript" setting
6. Slide the JavaScript setting control to the right to enable it
7. JavaScript is now enabled

Thanks!

Comment: I have tried the above mentioned steps for Issue 2 but still i am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Both issues are because Microsoft has replaced UIWebView with WKWebView in their implementation (UIWebView is obsolete on iOS). All You need to do is replace `app.Query(c=>c.WebView())` with `app.Query(c=>c.Class("WKWebView"))` for iOS. If you want to inspect web view, use `app.Query(c=>c.Class("WKWebView").Css("*"))`